# New Relic Data gives Wrong page views URL after New Relic script added via DTM

Tags: aem, adobe-analytics

We have added a new relic script via DTM,

and New Relic Data shows wrong Page URL, it shows Page views as DTM URL, not actual page views,

this happening because DTM will compile all scripts and executes the script with in a iFrame. so New Relic is considering iframe url as request URL.

any one have idea how to fix this using DTM ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/load_order.html), there are 4 types of **Javascript / 3rd Party Tag** containers.

It sounds like you chose **Non-Sequential HTML** container type, which appends a DTM hosted iframe to the page, with your code in it.  To append your code to the parent page, you must change the tag type to either **Sequential HTML**, or convert the tag to pure javascript and use **Sequential Javascript** or **Non-Sequential Javascript** type.

**Side note:** make sure to read the document page I provided above to ensure the type you choose is compatible with when you have it set to output (top of page, bottom of page, dom ready, window load)